# Definition of $\sigma(X) = \{ X^{-1}(B): B \in \mathcal{B} \}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Definition of $\sigma(X) = \{ X^{-1}(B): B \in \mathcal{B} \}$. [image]

Could someone explain why $\sigma(X)$ does not contain the union of the sets $\{X =1 \}$ and $\{X = 0\}$ but $\sigma(Y)$ does?

Comment: On your list of the elements of $\sigma(X)$, the $\Sigma$ should be $\Omega$, which *is* the union of $\{X=0\}$ and $\{X=1\}$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Hmm, but what about the element $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$ what is their union?

Comment: $\{(0,1)\}\cup\{(1,2)\}=\{(0,1),(1,2)\}$. But notice that $\{(0,1)\}$ is not an element of $\sigma(X)$ or of $\sigma(Y)$. (Ditto for $\{(1,2)\}$.

Comment: I see, I am just thinking about it the wrong way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it help to view it like this?

$\sigma(X) = \big\{ \mathcal X\times\{1,2,3,4,5,6\} : \mathcal X\in\mathcal P(\{0,1\})\big\}$

$$\begin{array}{rl:l}\sigma(X) = \Big\{ & \{\}, & \varnothing \\ & \{0\}\times\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}, & \{X=0\} \\ & \{1\}\times\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}, & \{X=1\}
\\ & \{0,1\}\times\{1,2,3,4,5,6\} & \Omega \textsf{ aka }\{X=0\}\cup \{X=1\} \\ \Big\} & \end{array}$$

$\sigma(Y) = \big\{ \{0,1\}\times\mathcal Y : \mathcal Y\in\mathcal P(\{1,2,3,4,5,6\})\big\}$

$$\begin{array}{rl:l}\sigma(Y) = \Big\{ & \{\}, & \varnothing \\ & \{0,1\}\times\{1\}, & \{Y=1\} \\ & \{0,1\}\times\{2\}, & \{Y=2\}
\\ & \{0,1\}\times\{3\} & \{Y=3\} \\ & \vdots & \vdots \\ & \{0,1\}\times\{1,2\} & \{Y=1\}\cup\{Y=2\} \\ & \vdots & \vdots \\ & \{0,1\}\times\{5,6\} & \{Y=5\}\cup\{Y=6\} \\ & \{0,1\}\times\{1,2,3\} & \big\{Y\in\{1,2,3\}\big\} \\ & \vdots & \vdots \\ & \vdots & \vdots \\ & \{0,1\}\times\{1,2,3,4,5,6\} & \Omega \\ \Big\} \end{array}$$

So $\sigma(X)$ does contain the event $\{X=0\}\cup\{X=1\}$ because, since $0$ and $1$ are the only evaluations of $X$, that union is in fact $\Omega$.   
$\sigma(Y)$ contains many more unions of the atoms ($\{Y=y\}$) because the power set of dice rolls is larger than that of coin flips.

$$\lvert \mathcal P\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\rvert = 2^6 \\ \lvert\mathcal P\{0,1\}\rvert = 2^2$$